# rails 4, postgres and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been following a few guides surrounding storing arrays with rails 4 and postgres, but I keep getting snagged with this error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "run_times" is of type character varying[] but expression is of type character varying at character 35
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Here is the SQL that is being executed by rails:

```
UPDATE "models" SET "run_times" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "models"."id" = $3  [["run_times", "{0,2}"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-07 17:44:47.480675"], ["id", 1]]
```

Which is generated by the controller using (as an example):

```
@model.run_times = ["0", "2"]
```

Is there something I'm missing?

--

Interestingly enough, this seems to work in rails console:

```
@model = Model.find(1)
@model.run_times = ["123", "456"]
@model.save
```

--

Here's the migration I used:

```
class AddRunTimesToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :models, :run_times, :text, array: true, default: '{}'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing in strings, just to double check is your run_times column set like this in your schema for that model's table?

```
t.string :run_times, array: true, default: '{}'
```

Comment: Yeah, it is. Confirmed type in in psql: character varying[]

Comment: What happens from rails console when you try doing `@model.run_times << ["0", "2"]` and then save

Comment: Strange, whatever is happening in the controller when you are setting run_times and then saving is causing ActiveRecord to interpret it as only a string or text value instead of an actual Postgres array

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the usual advice is to define string-based arrays as text, not string, in PostgreSQL. I would "down" the migration, and change the type to a text array.

Comment: Switched it over and getting same error, different expectation; `column "run_times" is of type text[] but expression is of type character varying`

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here's what I needed to do:

- instead of `permit(:run_times)` it needed to be `permit(run_times: [])`
- type in rails migration is string, not text
- restart the server after migrations

Comment: In rails 4 it *usually* updates and works just fine, in most cases.. but nonetheless a face palm.